# Licenses TFS 2013 and Visual Studio/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, tfs, licensing

I've read [Visual Studio and MSDN Licensing White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).

But unfortunately it isn't clear for me, I would like confirm with you that it's not illegal.

My enterprise already has a Premium MSDN subscription.
This subscription gives a licence of TFS that includes a `CAL` and an `SQL Server` licence for TFS.

If I understand the whitepaper correctly:

- Each developer who has `Visual Studio 2013 Premium` doesn't need a `license CAL` and **has full features** with `TFS`. They can access to the web interface, too.
- Each developer who has `Eclipse` doesn't need a `licence CAL` since `TFS Everywhere` is free (with the addon for `Eclipse`). The developers **don't have** full features but they can create/update/delete all issues. They can access to the web interface in order to change the issues.
- Each analyst of our team needs a `license CAL` in order to use the web interface and create/update/delete issues in project, don't they?
- The manager of the team needs to have a `license CAL`, don't they?

If each analyst and manager need a `license CAL`, they could install `Visual Studio` from the MSDN subscription in order to avoid a paid license or isn't it correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: I'm agree with you, you can close it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everybody who accesses TFS requires a CAL.  If a developer has VS 2013 Premium + MSDN, then he gets the CAL via that.  If a developer is an Eclipse developer (and doesn't have Visual Studio) then you need to purchase a CAL for them separately (Team Explorer Everywhere is free, but does not include a TFS CAL).

Comment: I guess the TFS users also need a Sharepoint CAL per seat, too.

Comment: Not if you use the SharePoint Foundation (or WSS).  You only need to purchase SharePoint CAL's if you choose to use the higher end SharePoint Server.